# How to encode a plain text into Json/Javascript string text?

Tags: c#, json, encoding, character-encoding

I want to return in the SQL table content in to a JSON format in C#
as per http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html,
The input type is plaintext, ISO-Latin-1

> Baden-Württemberg

and output type is JSON/Javascript/Java - String text

> "Baden-W\u00FCrttemberg"

How could I do in C# .Net

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

For reference: 
[How can I transform string to UTF-8 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057434/how-can-i-transform-string-to-utf-8-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Unfortunately I get the output Baden-W�rttemberg

Comment: Try  byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString); It worked for me at least. Idea is to encode your string as UTF8 then you can easily decode it