# Aplication crashes when calling function from dll for character-set conversion

Tags: c#, character-encoding, pinvoke, dllimport

funcion on C

```
TCHAR* __stdcall W1251ToUtf8(CHAR* str)//функция пребразования строки из Windows-1251 в Unicode
{
    int wsize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, NULL, 0);
    TCHAR* result = new TCHAR[wsize*sizeof(TCHAR)]; 
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str, -1, result, wsize);
    return result;
}
```

function declaration in c# project

```
[DllImport("D://EncodingStringData.dll", EntryPoint = "W1251ToUtf8")]
        static extern string W1251ToUtf8(string str);
```

function call

```
string TextForEncoding = ReadFromFile();
string OutText = W1251ToUtf8(TextForEncoding);
```

first time app crash without any reason, then im add try catch

```
try
            { 
                string TextForEncoding = ReadFromFile();
                string OutText = W1251ToUtf8(TextForEncoding);
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

and i catch accessviolationexception, now crashing againg without reason.

So anyone know what i need to do?

Comment: Did you compile with `/unsafe`?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: This function is bananas. The name and comment imply it converts Windows-1251 characters into UTF-8, which is not at all what it does -- it converts UTF-8 to UTF-16. Regardless of what it does or is supposed to do, there's a perfectly safe managed equivalent that does not require calling it at all. Use `System.Text.Encoding` to convert between encodings and don't bother with this.

Comment: Jeroen is right. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057434/how-can-i-transform-string-to-utf-8-in-c) for some sample code

Comment: i should do it through unsafe code and dont ask me why

Comment: @dennismeister I'll give a -1 and don't ask me why

Comment: @IanH. He's just using p-invoke.

Comment: @Abion47 program has exited with code -1073740940 (0xc0000374).

Comment: That exit code doesn't tell me much of anything at all. Rather than Google it, though, I will reiterate what others have said. There is a much simpler and safer method of doing exactly this without having to bother with C code or P/Invokes, and insisting on this method after knowing that is clinically insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems:

- You pass 1251 text but ask it to be treated as UTF8. So the API function call likely fails. You don't check return value for failure.
- Your input is 8 bit text, your output if 16 bit text, but your pinvoke assumes 8 bit for both.
- A return value type of `string` leads to the returned pointer being passed `CoTaskMemFree` for deallocation.

The exit code is STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION which suggests the final bullet is the immediate problem. Fix that by returning `IntPtr` and convert to text with `Marshal.PtrToStringUni`. And also export a deallocator. Or allocate off a shared heap. Or return a COM `BStr`. Indeed use any of the correct ways to return a string.

Having fixed that problem you'll need to fix the others too.

Quite why you won't use `System.Text.Encoding` is beyond me.

Comment: i dont use c# tool coz my project name is "using win32/64 api dll in c# project"

Comment: what i need to do with another construction Declaration on C CHAR* __stdcall Utf8ToW1251(TCHAR* str); Wich types i need to use in C# code? private static extern string Utf8ToW1251(IntPtr str); IntPtr TextForEncodingInInt = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni (TextForEncoding); string OutText = Utf8ToW1251(TextForEncodingInInt); its didnt work

Comment: Well no. You'll need to encode the UTF8 manually. And your function will need to deallocation the returned value too.

Comment: so i need to put into function string and take IntPtr?

Comment: This is a different question.