# Getting string in right format from byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, type-conversion, byte

I have a problem converting byte array to string in right format. Im reading byte array over TCP socket, it gives me bytes, one of the bytes is **byte 158**.
If i read string with:

```
Encoding.Latin1.GetString(data)
```

it gives me string in format
"blahblah\u009eblahblah".
\u009e is the code for letter ž.
The sting i need should be
"blahblah**ž**blahblah".
How i can get the string in the right format?

Alredy tried other encodings like ACSII, UTF8 etc.. none of them got me the right format.

**EDIT**
some code example how im getting the data and what im doing with it:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(terminal.server_IP, terminal.port);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;

        string message = "some message for terminal";
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Latin1.GetBytes(message);

        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        string rsp = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
```

**EDIT2**
So, i dont know what was the problem... just created a new project for .NET Framework versoin 4.7.2, in that project its worikng fine. Thanks for suggestions for everyone, credit goes to @Jeppe Stig Nielsen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057434/how-can-i-transform-string-to-utf-8-in-c

Comment: That looks a lot like unicode. I really wonder why UTF8 didn't work. Can you post a [mcve] for us to reproduce this?

Comment: Is it that the byte array actually contains the textual representation of Unicode characters? how are you viewing the results. where are you getting the data from?

Comment: Could you provide the *byte array*, please? You can do it as `string dump = string.Join(" ", msg); Console.WriteLine(dump);`. Then, please, provide the desired *string*

Comment: Looks like something may have already incorrectly decoded some data using the wrong encoding.

Comment: By the way, `\u009e` is NOT the code for `ž` - it's the code for the unprintable character "PRIVACY MESSAGE". Any escape sequence beginning with `\u` in a string is supposed to be a Unicode value (which is why it starts with `u` for Unicode). Something has messed up somewhere before you receive that string, it seems.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko i dont have problems with msg, it work fine, the problem is with the rsp with decoding of data (i think i have the wrong Encoding type, but if i try with UTF8 or other, it gives me some strange symbols like: Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] {158}) = "�"

Comment: @Matthew Watson - so the problem may be on the terminal side if i read the data out with stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); ?

Comment: @Taliga there are lot of smart people trying to help you here, If someone asks you to supply something they feel is pertinent to the clarity of the question, you should oblige and not discount such requests

Comment: @Taliga Yes, it looks like some incorrect encoding is being done BEFORE the string is returned to you via TCP/IP.

Comment: @Taliga Yes, `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data)` works immediately on old .NET Framework. I would be interested to know if your project targeting .NET 5.0 (under Windows) would work if you said `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` first (may need new assembly reference, maybe there is a simple tip near the word `CodePagesEncodingProvider` to add the reference (modifies the project file)), and then after that do `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data)`. Also, find out if `"Windows-1250"` is better (they agree on `0x9E`, however).

Comment: I'm guessing whatever is sending you the data is not encoding it correctly in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Encoding.Latin1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.latin1) is not usable in your case. True Latin 1 does not contain ž (LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON).

If you want Windows-1252, use

```
Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data)
```

This will turn bytes of decimal value `158` (hex `0x9E`) into lowercase ž.

---

It may also be `"Windows-1250"` that you have. What other non-English letters do you expect in your text? Compare [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250); they are different in general, but both agree that hex byte `0x9E` (dec `158`) is ž.

---

When on a .NET Core system where the above does not work immediately, attempt to execute:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var goodText = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(data);
```

Finding the type [`CodePagesEncodingProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.codepagesencodingprovider) may need a reference to the assembly *System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll*.

Comment: tried Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252") got error: 'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.

Comment: @Taliga You are right, I was on the old .NET Framework (which also explains why I did not see [`Latin1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.latin1) property which is new in .NET 5). You need to figure out if you have [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) or similar. Edit: Are you under Windows, or another OS?

Comment: Windows-1250 throws same error, im under windows, WPF project with .NET 5.0

Comment: @Taliga I added more to my answer above. See if it works.